# JQuery and CSS with position absolute, height 100% not working in IE11 and Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I am building a "view some of our products" section into a new website.  When the image of the product is hovered over, it should fade the image amd then slide the title of the image up over the top.

I have created a JSFIDDLE with all this working exactly as I want, and it works in Chrome, and Safari, but in IE11 and Firefox it renders unexpected results.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="outerSqrProducts">
        <div class="sqrProductsImage">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.avenir-accessories.co.uk/media/4367/beewi-fiat-500-white.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="ic_caption" id="caption1">
            <h2 class="centerText">Title</h2>   
         </div>
    </div>


    <div class="outerSqrProducts">
       <div class="sqrProductsImage"> <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.avenir-accessories.co.uk/media/4367/beewi-fiat-500-white.jpg"/>
        </a>


        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="ic_caption">
                <h2 class="centerText">Title</h2>   
        </div>
    </div>

    <body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #0097F0;
}
.centerText {
    text-align: center;
}
.outerSqrProducts
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 234px;
    width: 234px;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    position: relative;

}
.sqrProductsImage 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.sqrProductsImage img {
    max-height: 234px;
    max-width: 234px;
}
.overlay, .ic_caption {
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 151, 240, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.ic_caption {
    background-color: rgba(0, 151, 240, 0.8);
    height: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = $('.outerSqrProducts');
    var overlay = $('.overlay');
    var title = $('.ic_caption');
    var speed = 500;

    div.each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'image' + i);
        var divId = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#' + divId).hover(function () {
            // make background opaque
            $('#' + divId).find('.overlay').fadeIn(speed);
            // slide down the title
            $('#' + divId).find('.ic_caption').slideDown(speed);
        },

        function () {
            $('#' + divId).find('.ic_caption').slideUp(speed);
            $('#' + divId).find('.overlay').fadeOut(speed);

        });
    });

});
```

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aFG9k/

In IE11, it doesn't apply the full height of the overlay div, no not all of the image is faded out.

In Firefox, it's trying to fade out and slide the title up to the space around the div with the image in it, rather than in the div itself (very bizarre!).

Have I done something obviously stupid?

Any help appreciated.n

Comment: Have you set the image to `display:block`? Sometimes it makes a difference.

Comment: Well, I'm using `display:none` so not sure where I can put it?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the `display: table-cell;` in `.outerSqrProducts`. It is likely because of [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168) in Firefox, that relative positioning on elements with table-cell display does not work.

Floating the product containers instead, using `float: left;` will make the overlay show up as intended.

Comment: OK, removing that does solve the problem thank you :) however I was using that to ensure the images were centered vertically in their little squares.  Do you know of another way I can do that?

Comment: Is the image size consistent? I see that the height of `.outerSqrProducts` is set to 234px, so if the images can be of constant height you could simply use `padding-top`. You can also check out [this fix](http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute), which enables you to use `display: table-cell` but requires setting `height: 100%` on the elements and their container.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  I have set max height and max width on the image to make it fit into the square(and stay in proportion).  But in most cases the images are wider than they are tall so I don't know how tall the images will be when scaled down to 234px wide.

Comment: In that case you can set `line-height: 234px` on `.sqrProductsImage` and `vertical-align: middle` on the images and they will be centered vertically as long as they are less than 234px high. There are also alternative methods [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).